# Create dynamically angular 2+ reference ngModel variable for input

Tags: angular

I want to create dynamic ngModel input reference variable for checking required validation.

Here is my implementation:

```
<div *ngFor="let priceId of prices">
  <input [(ngModel)]="getPriceValue(priceId)" #price="ngModel"/>
  <div *ngIf="price.invalid && (routePrice.dirty || price.touched)" class="invalid-feedback">
    required field!
 </div>
</div>
```

For single referencing it works but multiple referencing with same reference `#price` it doesnt work.
Because it needs unique reference variable.

I want to set like this:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="getPriceValue(priceId)" #price_{{priceId}}="ngModel"/>
```

But it doesnt work.

How can I set dynamic reference variable in angular 2+ ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the HTML File:

```html
<form #f="ngForm">
  <input [(ngModel)]="getPriceValue(priceId)" #price="ngModel" name="price" required/> 
  <button class="btn" (click)="onClick(f)">btn</button>
</form>
```

In the TS file:

```js
onClick(f: NgForm) {
  this.checkForm(f);
}

checkForm(form) {
  const control = form.controls;
  Object.keys(control).forEach(controlName =>
    control[controlName].markAsTouched());
  Object.keys(control).forEach(controlName =>
    control[controlName].markAsDirty());
  const data = [];
  Object.keys(control).map((key) => {
    const newObj = {key, value: control[key]};
    data.unshift(newObj);
  });
  let title = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    const error = data[i].value.errors ? Object.keys(data[i].value.errors) : [];
    const inputKey = data[i].key;
    for (let x = 0; x < error.length; x++) {
      title = inputKey.toUpperCase() + '_' + error[x].toUpperCase();
      alert(title);
    }
  }
}
```

I do this with dynamic validation using this input name and validation attribute.